# Why my android app stops when i set the text value of a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

I have two layouts. The first one:

```
<LinearLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/edit_text_val">
                </EditText>
                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/continue"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Continue"
                        android:onClick="newConfirm"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the second one:

```
<LinearLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/text_view_val">
                </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I click the button of the first layout I go to the second layout and want to set as text value of the TextView
the string entered in the EditText of the first layout. I do this in the newConfirm method:

```
public void newConfirm(View view){
        EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text_val);
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_val);
        tv.setText(et.getText().toString());
    }
```

But when I click the button my app stops working...
**Unfortunately MobileApp has stopped**

Any idea??

Comment: Please post Logcat too..

Comment: Probably there is NullPointerException thrown on this line tv.setText(et.getText().toString()); Provide Logcat error and your code where you setup ui and load these 2 layouts.

Comment: Yes from the logcat I see it is a :  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1794)

Comment: you have find button id ?

Comment: If you are using two different xml then u have to pass value in different screen.

Comment: your edittext and textview in 2 different layouts???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly set the value of your `EditText` from the first activity.

You are supposed to pass the value of `EditText` through `Intent` from first activity to second activity and then in your second activity get from intent and set into `TextView`.

Try out as below:

```
public void newConfirm(View view){
        EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text_val);

         Intent intent =new Intent(FistLayout.this,Secondlayout.class);
           intent.putExtra("value",et.getText().toString());
           startActivity(intent);
    }
```

In your second activity write below code in `onCreate`

```
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_val);
    String value=getIntent().getString("value");
    tv.setText(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not working because the text view is in different layout. You need to pass your data by intent to next activity and then display text there.see this [example](http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/241-lesson-28-extras-passing-data-using-intent.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your EditText and TextView resides in two different layouts.Then how can you use findViewbyId for both of them in a single class??Pass the Edittext value through Intent in the 2nd layout:

```
 Intent i=new Intent(FistLayout.this,Secondlayout.class);
  i.putExtra("key",ed.getText().toString());
  startActivity(i);
```

In the second layout:

```
 String str=getIntent().getExtras.getString("key");
  textView.setText(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

its very simple just define this under you onclick functionality where you intent to next activity

Define Onclick like this under OnCREATE

```
  YourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                 next();
            }

        });
```

**Then write this function anywhere in your activity**

```
    public void next()
   {

  String strMessage = YourTEXT.getText().toString());

// so on you can directly set values
// you have to just set values in string                      

  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nextactivity.class)   
  i.putExtra("new_variable_name",strMessage);


  startActivity(i);  

}
```

**Then in your next activity retrieve it via**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String var="";

      if (extras != null)
      {

        String value= extras.getString("new_variable_name");       
        value= var;
        yourtext2.setText(var);

      }
```